# nfs-kernel-server installation : file does not exist

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, nfs, init.d

I am extremely new to Ubuntu and need to work on EdX platform. I need to install the NFS Client on Ubuntu 12.04 for the same. I used the following

```
stuti@stuti:/$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```

However this gives me an error as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nfs-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nfs-common nfs-kernel-server
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/355 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,222 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package nfs-common.
(Reading database ... 200367 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking nfs-common (from .../nfs-common_1%3a1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nfs-kernel-server.
Unpacking nfs-kernel-server (from .../nfs-kernel-server_1%3a1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up nfs-common (1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1) ...
statd start/running, process 4574
gssd stop/pre-start, process 4603
idmapd start/running, process 4643
Setting up nfs-kernel-server (1:1.2.5-3ubuntu3.1) ...
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server: file does not exist
dpkg: error processing nfs-kernel-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nfs-kernel-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get autoremove nfs-kernel-server
sudo apt-get autoremove nfs-common
```

After these, I tried to install but I keep getting the same error. `apt-get update` or `upgrade` also do not help and give the same error.

I am clueless as to where can I find this missing file as stated in the output. I tried to google about this problem but none of the solutions I came across have helped or I have not been able to understand some of them.

Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
apt-get purge nfs-kernel-server
apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
```